# Update previous rows based on the current row on CSV with python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.6

This is my CSV doc. :

```
Product code,Year,Month,Measurement period,Rainfall amount
1a,1962,01,0,01
1s,1962,01,1,02
1d,1962,01,0,03
1f,1962,01,0,04
1z,1962,01,0,05
1x,1962,01,0,06
1c,1962,01,3,07
1q,1962,01,0,01
1w,1962,01,0,02
1e,1962,01,0,03
1r,1962,01,0,04
1t,1962,01,4,05
1y,1962,01,0,06
1k,1962,01,0,07
```

And this is the code :

```
import csv



path = r"C:\FEWS\Sample.csv"
fields = ['Product code','Year','Month','Measurement period','Rainfall amount']
output2 = r"C:\FEWS\Sample2.csv"


with open(path,'r') as x, open(output2, 'w', newline='') as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(x, fieldnames=fields)
    writer= csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fields)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            if int(row['Rainfall amount']) > 1:
                Measure_period = row['Measurement period']

                for x in range(int(Measure_period) -1):
                    pass
                    # Update the previous rows
        except ValueError:
            pass
        writer.writerow(row)
```

What I am trying to do is if the Measurement period is higher than 1 and let's say it is 3 modify only rainfall amount of previous 3 rows coming before the current row and make their rainfall amount equal to current row.

Output should be like this :

```
Product code,Year,Month,Measurement period,Rainfall amount
1a,1962,01,0,01
1s,1962,01,1,02
1d,1962,01,0,03
1f,1962,01,0,07
1z,1962,01,0,07
1x,1962,01,0,07
1c,1962,01,3,07
1q,1962,01,0,05
1w,1962,01,0,05
1e,1962,01,0,05
1r,1962,01,0,05
1t,1962,01,4,05
1y,1962,01,0,06
1k,1962,01,0,07
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this basically, what it does it add the rows to a list as they are processed. This allows you to go back to the previous row if you need to update it. It only writes the output after the full input file is processed. **This would not be an ideal solution if this csv is very large as this approach would use a lot of memory**.

This will update the previous rows based on what the `Measurement Period` is. It checks to make sure that the update falls within the range of the list. For example if the second row has a `Measurement Period` of 4 you should only update the first row right not 4 rows?

This has the possibility of updating two rows twice aswell, for example. What if row two has a `Measurement Period` of 2 and row 3 has a `Measurement Period` of 4. The third rows `Rainfall Value` will overwrite rows 1 and 2. Does that make sense?

Make sure and test this out to see if it covers your scenrios.

```
import csv

path = "Sample.csv"
fields = ['Product code','Year','Month','Measurement period','Rainfall amount']
output2 = "Sample2.csv"


with open(path,'r') as x, open(output2, 'w', newline='') as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(x, fieldnames=fields)
    writer= csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fields)
    rows = []
    for row in reader:

    try:
        if int(row['Measurement period']) > 1:
            for i in range(int(row['Measurement period'])):
                if len(rows)-(i+1) <= len(rows)-1 and len(rows)-(i+1) >= 0:
                    rows[len(rows)-(i+1)]['Rainfall amount'] = row['Rainfall amount']
        rows.append(row)
    except ValueError:
        pass
writer.writerows(rows)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Actually the output is not wrong rainfall value of 1q(Product code) is equal to 05 because the measurement period of the 1t is 4 so it should modify 4 previous rows.
If it was 2 it should modify 2 previous rows

Comment: @MehmetAli I updated it to take into account the Measurement Period to determine the number of rows to update. Test it and see if it does what you are looking for.